# Does StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(String) escapes $ symbol, too?

Tags: java, stringescapeutils

I want to escape $ symbol along with other characters like '<', '>' etc. So just wanted to know if StringEscapeUtils supported this. And if not, how can I escape it?

Comment: If only there was a way to find out if it gets replaced...

Comment: Some JavaScript heavily uses $. But one can do `html.replace("$", "%24")`

Comment: @JoopEggen This link shows "&#36;" for $ - http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php  It this somthing different?

Comment: @mmk I was wrong, `&#36;` is better for HTML text.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no. You can try it with this code:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("<b>Hello, World!</b>$")
```

Outputs

```
&lt;b&gt;Hello, World!&lt;/b&gt;$
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested doing the following from commons-text 1.1 after commons-lang 3 deprecated `StringEscapeUtils`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("$ % > < = #"));
}
```

Output `$ % &gt; &lt; = #`

It does not escape "$" out of the box, but the new Utils in commons-text enable users to extend it. Read [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/commons-lang-3-improved-and-powerful-StringEscapeUtils) for examples. Here is a small one, but the article shows more advanced possibilities:

```
Map<CharSequence, CharSequence> added = new HashMap<>();
added.put("$", "foo");
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_HTML4
                                    .with(new LookupTranslator(added))
                                    .translate("$ % > < = #"));
```

Output `foo % &gt; &lt; = #`

Comment: If I want to do it manually (using replaceAll) what should be the value, any idea?

Comment: Whether you do it manually or with the escape utils, the code you found and mentioned in your reply to Joop should be the one. The percent encoded one is for URLs.